# Prevent pgloader from casting tinyint(1) to boolean

Tags: mysql, postgresql, pgloader

I'm migrating a MySQL database to Postgres using pgloader.

According to this documentation: https://pgloader.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref/mysql.html#default-mysql-casting-rules the default for tinyint(1) is to cast it to a boolean.

```
type tinyint to boolean when (= 1 precision) using tinyint-to-boolean
```

Instead, I want to keep these as smallint (on the postgres side).

I'm not having much luck overriding this default behavior. Everything I have tried results in a vague error. Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Does it not work if you override the default?  https://pgloader.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref/mysql.html

Comment: I have tried a few ways including the one from this example: https://github.com/dimitri/pgloader/blob/master/test/parse/hans.goeuro.load#L24


At

  
  CAST type tinyint when (= precision 1) to boolean drop typemod using bits-to-boolean
  
                                                                                      ^ (Line 7, Column 84, Position 335)

In context COMMAND:

While parsing COMMAND. Expected:

     the character Tab
  or the character Newline
 ...

Answer (score 0):

```
  CAST type int when unsigned to bigint,
  type int with extra auto_increment when unsigned to bigserial,
  type tinyint to smallint,
  type tinyint  when (= precision 1) to smallint keep typemod,
  type tinyint  when (= precision 3) to smallint keep typemod;
```

Use something like above and it will work, make sure that what ever precision you have for tinyint in mysql mention it in your CAST and it should work